# How to marshal anonymous struct?

Tags: go, struct

Why do I get `{}` when trying to marshal an anonymous struct?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    js, err := json.Marshal(struct{id int}{123})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write(js)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lEqJ1uj1ezS

Comment: Why are you using `os.Stdout.Write()`?  `fmt.Print` forwards directly to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/XNAKovWGhxk

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    jsonString, err := json.Marshal(
        struct{
            Id int `json:"theKeyYouWantToUse"`
        } {
            123
        },
    )

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }

    os.Stdout.Write(jsonString)
}
```

You are not exporting id attribute, change it to Id

Comment: The json field tag is not necessary unless you need a different field name in the struct vs. the JSON.

Answer (score 8):

If you use following struct, Marshal method will ignore `id` as it is not exported.

```
struct{id int}{123}
```

You need to export them to keep them in conversion process.

> In Go, a name is exported if it begins with a capital letter

```
js, _ := json.Marshal(struct{Id int}{123})
os.Stdout.Write(js)
// {"Id":123}
```